# html5 audio tag not working in IE11 and Edge

Tags: html, html5-audio

I'm new to this forum and have looked at some previous answers, but can't find any that help.

I thought html5 audio was supposed to be simple?? i can't get it to work in either IE11 or Edge:

```html
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="music/Aranjuez.ogg" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="music/Aranjuez.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element
 </audio>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is or isn't happening in IE11/Edge?

Comment: You can try this https://kolber.github.io/audiojs/
it solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You mixed up the file types:

```
<source src="music/Aranjuez.ogg" type="audio/mpeg">
<source src="music/Aranjuez.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
```

should be

```
<source src="music/Aranjuez.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="music/Aranjuez.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
```

Comment: Doh! When you stare at something too long, you miss the obvious! Thanks.